# Symfony submit a search form with categories and region

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I got a search form in page's header that must to submit to my SearchController and be handeld by searchAction in case of the user input only the query string.

This form got the ability to search in selected category and country region.

[image: search form]

So the user can make the search in all category and all region or select category and all region or select category and region

[image: esearch form with category and region selected]

How I can handle this? I've made the controller action that actually work when i put the data in url.

Here is my search class using QueryBuilder:

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("cerca/{query}", name="search")
 */
public function searchAction(Request $request,$query)
{
$results = $this->getDoctrine()
           ->getRepository('AppBundle:Ads')
           ->createQueryBuilder('p')
           ->where("p.name LIKE '%$query%'")
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

return $this->render('search\search.html.twig', [
    //'pagination'=>$pagination,
    'query' => $query,
    'region' => 'Italia',
    'results' => $results,
    ]);
}
/**
 * @Route("cerca/{region}/{query}", name="search_regioni")
 */
public function searchRegionAction($region,$query)
{
    $results = $this->getDoctrine()
           ->getRepository('AppBundle:Ads')
           ->createQueryBuilder('p')
           ->where("p.name LIKE '%$query%'")
           ->andWhere("p.region Like '%$region%'")
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

    $region = ucfirst($region);
    return $this->render('search/search.html.twig', [
        'region' => $region,
        'query'  => $query,
    ]);
}
/**
 * @Route("cerca/{category}/{query}", name="search_categorie")
 */
public function searchCategoryAction($category,$query)
{
    $results = $this->getDoctrine()
           ->getRepository('AppBundle:Ads')
           ->createQueryBuilder('p')
           ->where("p.name LIKE '%$query%'")
           ->andWhere("p.region Like '%$region%'")
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

    $category = ucfirst($category);
    return $this->render('search/search.html.twig', [
        'region' => 'Italia',
        'category' => $category,
        'query'  => $query,
    ]);
}
/**
 * @Route("cerca/{category}/{region}/{query}", name="search_categorie_regioni")
 */
public function searchCategoryRegionAction($category,$region,$query)
{
    $results = $this->getDoctrine()
           ->getRepository('AppBundle:Ads')
           ->createQueryBuilder('p')
           ->where("p.name LIKE '%$query%'")
           ->andWhere("p.region LIKE '%$region%'")
           ->andWhere("p.category LIKE '%$category%'")
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

    $category = ucfirst($category);
    $region = ucfirst($region);
    return $this->render('search/search.html.twig', [
        'region' => $region,
        'category' => $category,
        'query'  => $query,
    ]);
 }
}
```

How I can make the form submit to this controller? How to handle the different cases?

I think my logic is wrong too, symfony don't know if I search for a category or country region, how can I improve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of having different actions you should submit the data and store it in a ValueObject, e.g. a `Search` object:

```
class Search {
    public $query;
    public $category;
    public $region;
}
```

You could also create a `SearchType` that binds a form to the value object and provides some validation and constraints, e.g. create a ChoiceLoader that loads the available categories from a database and checks that the selected one is valid. After submitting and validating the form input you retrieve the search object from the form and use it to build your Doctrine-Query. In case region is empty, e.g. not selected you just omit it from the query like this:

```
/** @var Search $search **/
$search = $form->getData();
$queryBuilder = $this->getDoctrine()
   ->getRepository('AppBundle:Ads')
   ->createQueryBuilder('p')
$queryBuilder->where($queryBuilder->expr()->like('p.name', "%{$search->query}%");
if (null != $search->region) {
    $queryBuilder->andWhere('region = :region')
        ->setParameter('region', $search->region);
}
$results = $queryBuilder->createQuery()->getResults();
```

Some things to note:

- Do not just inject the variables into the where-clauses. This is a security problem. You should use parameters and the expression builder to safeguard against SQL injection.
- You can chain clauses in the query builder (like you do above) or split them up, like I do in the if condition.
- Since the form is already connected to the Search-object the fields should be pre-filled with the last inserted values, so you don't have to pass around the input separately.
- I'm not 100% sure the `LIKE`-expression will work as expected. It can be somewhat tricky. You should search for how to use it properly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you be more specific? where I must to put this code? I'm new to symfony.

Comment: I'm not using FormBuilder cause the form isn't on a single page but in the header that I embed in twig, should I switch to FB and maybe create another Controller to be included in pages? It's possible to do this? and how?

Comment: Best practices recommends creating FormType-classes and then usong the `$this->createForm()` in Controller (when it extends the BaseController). I would probably go with that. Even if its a header you could have a specific controller+action, see Embedding controllers: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html